# Performance difference between using neo4j REST API with and without cypher?

Tags: neo4j

From what I read here: [neo4j cypher rest api](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-cypher.html#rest-api-use-parameters)

you can get a cypher speed up when using parameters wherever possible in order to let the server cache query plans.

So is there a speed up or performance gain when I use

cypher with parameters on the rest api

vs

rest api without using cypher queries?

Or in other words, if I have to use the neo4j rest api, would it be a good idea(performance wise) to only use the cypher queries portion with parameters vs the rest of the api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cypher is probably pretty close for simple operations, like adding a node, or changing the properties of a node (although raw REST might be slightly faster), and Cypher is certainly faster for more complex operations that involve traversals. So, yes, I think you could get away with using Cypher exclusively pretty easily.

Comment: So this article isnt relevant anymore?
http://java.dzone.com/articles/get-full-neo4j-power-using

Comment: No, if you want maximum performance over REST, you can write the equivalent of stored procedures (unmanaged extensions) in the native Java API. They are certainly faster than cypher, usually, up to 2 orders of magnitude by my testing (for queries that Cypher is particularly bad at). The question was really asking about a comparison between REST and Cypher over REST, though, unless I misunderstood.

Comment: Also, Cypher is a safe bet for 2.1 performance optimizations where they will be focusing on bringing Cypher closer to Java.